# Is there anything inherently wrong with the idea of temporarily saving user passwords inside the ServletContext?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, servletcontextlistener, servlet-listeners

Here is the premise, I am not allowed to use JavaScript or Cookies for this website.

However I do not wish to ask the user for their password for every essential task that requires their password for at least 15-30 minutes.

I also don't like the idea of saving their password to a temp file in case the program dies and is not able to erase it as scheduled.

So my plan is upon first contact, assign the user a unique randomly generated secure id/hash and attach it inside their generated HTML. And server side match their password to their id inside the ServletContext. This way for all their incoming requests I can match them without asking for password across all classes.

Also I will make sure to automatically erase their info from the ServletContext when their 15-30 minute expires.

So far it seems like to me this method avoids both JS and Cookies, also all the external storage methods that are at risk when the program dies. Yes the ServletContext is supposed to be global, but without their unique temporary id/hash no one will be able to impersonate them.

I am asking this question because I couldn't find anyone else asking the same question so I needed to make sure there isn't anything wrong with this method.

Comment: Personally I'd go with a more standard approach. I'd use custom HTTP headers to deliver that token. Is it a Java MVC based front-end? Are you using REST or SOAP for contacting de BE?

Comment: @Diego I am not using any frameworks, the server being used is tomcat if it matters, and the frontend does not use any JS of any kind. Depending on the post request, the response page is generated inside the java servlet. This is the first time I have heard of custom HTTP headers, if this method does not utilize JS, cookies, exposed HTML fields, or URL rewriting, then I will start learning about it as soon as possible if you believe it is better.

Comment: @Diego Can you explain how the custom HTTP header method will work so I have a better idea?

Comment: Don't mind me. Actually, what I proposed cannot be done without JS. You would need to POST the header containing the token, and AFAIK there isn't a way to do that with pure HTML. 

So... I'm just trying to better understand the context: You could use Authorization Basic (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization). This way you shouldn't need to implement functions with JS nor cookies. But you need to make sure that SSL is in place. May I ask why you can't use cookies?

Comment: Just so you know, your solution which is sending a hidden HTML field that contains the token, is valid. It is an old-school hack. The reason I'm asking you so many things is that nowadays there are more standard ways and preferably you shouldn't need to implement a "hack".

Comment: @Diego Looked up Authorization Basic but nothing prominent came up. I am using SSL and the server pretty much does force it. If you are talking about the unique SSL id each user has, i'm pretty sure I looked into that method some time ago and I could swear JS was required to get that ID or something along those lines. If I am wrong, let me know, if not i'll go ahead with my original plan since nothing seems to be out of place. I can't really answer the cookie question, it is simply a requirement.

Comment: @Diego Right, I cannot risk the password being cached or viewed client side so the exposed HTML hack is out the window.

Comment: @Diego I see your edit with the link now. I will now look into this SSL method, SSL is forced on the server so perhaps you did find a solution for me. Depending on how I can get this value.

Comment: Well, using basic authorization also stores the user and password in the clients browser cache. This is why usually cookies with tokens are implemented. If you can't use cookies, then I'd say your approach is correct. I don't see major drawbacks. The only advice I have is that I would probably refresh the token a bit more frequently.

Comment: @Diego well I'm glad I got the validation of another user at least. I just wasn't 100% sure if someone was going to come out and point out some obvious major flaw I missed.

Comment: The only flaw that I can think of right now is replay attacks. This is why I'd invalidate and refresh the token frequently (if not with each request).

Comment: Added an answer to reflect these comments. Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following restrictions:

1. No cookies allowed.
2. No JS allowed.
3. Caching credentials at client-side is not an option.

The proposed approach seems ok at first glance. However, I would suggest that you follow this guidelines:

1. Make sure replay attacks aren't possible. Since you can't hash and sign request at client-side, invalidate and refresh the tokens frequently (preferably with each request) at the back-end.
2. CSRF counter-measures should be in place.
3. SSL should be enforced.